# Retaining input values in C?

Tags: c, math

I have asked for the user to enter in several values to calculate an average, however I'd like to also calculate a gradient which uses the inputted values. How do I name these values so I can use them again? Thank you.

Here is what I have thus far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
    int n, i;
    float num[1000], total=0, mean;

    printf("Enter the amount of x-values:");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    while (n <= 0 || n > 1000) {
        printf("Print error. The number should in range of 0 to 1000.\n");
        printf("Please try to enter the amount again: ");
        scanf("%d", &n);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        printf("%d. Input x-value:", i+1);
        scanf("%f", &num[i]);
        total += num[i];
    }
    mean=total/n;
    printf("The mean of all the x-values entered is %.2f to 2 decimal places", mean);

    {
        float num[1000], total=0, mean;

        printf("Enter the amount of y-values:");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        while (n <= 0 || n > 1000) {
            printf("Print error. The number should in range of 0 to 1000.\n");
            printf("Please try to enter the amount again: ");
            scanf("%d",&n);
        }
        for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            printf("%d. Input y-value:", i+1);
            scanf("%f", &num[i]);
            total += num[i];
        }
        mean = total / n;
        printf("The mean of all the y-values entered is %.2f to 2 decimal places", mean);

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can name them as `int input_array[NUM_INPUTS];`

Comment: Sounds like a job for an array.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?  If so, show it.  It shouldn't be too painful.

Comment: @ryyker I'm a beginner and I have never used arrays, sorry about this

Comment: Is google down again ?

Comment: Thanks for the useless comment @MichaelWalz

Comment: That's true, thank you @ryyker

Comment: Well, one thing is, 'rolling/running average' questions have been continually posted on SO for the last week.  It's not a difficult assignment, but it appears again, and again, and again.  When an 'average' question turns up with no code at all then, with all the previous posts, it's very easy to come to the conclusion that such a post a is a no-effort homework question from some deadbeat student who is hell-bent of getting someone, anyone to do all his/her work for them.  To avoid appearing as such, post the code you have tried:)

Comment: @ryyker that is my problem, I have been set a project and I have chosen a task that requires me to get x and y values to produce averages and a gradient, I know what I want to happen but I'm not knowledgeable enough to implement it. This is what I have come up with so far (look in original question)

Comment: Hi @MartinJames you're spot on with your comments, so I have added my code to be more helpful

Comment: @ryyker I have and there's an error in line 36, there's conflicting types for 'get_int'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Naming the variable is really up to you, but `int gradient[NUM_ELEMENTS]; seems appropriate.  It is an array, which also seems appropriate if it's purpose is to assist in finding the gradient from a series of numbers.

*Steps could be:*
1) use printf to ask user for values, specify spaces or commas between values.  You can also specify a limit of values. Example `printf("enter 5 numbers separated by commas\n:");`
2) use scanf or similar to read values from standard input (the terminal) into the array: `scanf("%d,%d,%d,%d,%d", &gradient[0], &gradient[1], &gradient[2], &gradient[3], &gradient[4]);`
3) use the array an a function that will compute the gradient.

Simple example:
(where gradient computation, error checking, bounds checking etc. is all left to you)

```
int get_gradient(int a[5]);

int main(void) {
    int gradient[5];
    int iGradient=0;

    printf("enter 5 numbers separated by commas");
    scanf("%d,%d,%d,%d,%d", &gradient[0], &gradient[1], &gradient[2], &gradient[3], &gradient[4]); 
    iGradient = get_gradient(gradient);

    return 0;
}

int get_gradient(int a[5])
{
    return [do computation here using array a];
}
```

*Edit:*
The above example works only if you know the number of elements at compile time.  It uses an int array that has been created on the *stack*.  If you do not know how big of an array you will need until run-time, for example if user input determines the size, then the array size needs to be determined at run-time. One options is to create the variable needed on the *heap*.  (*[read about stack and heap here](http://gribblelab.org/CBootcamp/7_Memory_Stack_vs_Heap.html)*)  The following uses some techniques different from the simpler version above to get user input, including a function I called get_int(), which uses `scanf()` in conjunction with `strtol()`.  Here's the example:

```
int main(void) {
    char input[80]={0};
    char **dummy={0};
    long *gradient = {0};
    int iGradient=0;
    int arraysize;
    int i;
    char* fmt = "%[^\n]%*c";

    printf("how many numbers will be entered?");
    scanf(fmt, input);                     
    arraysize = strtol(input, dummy, 10);

    gradient = calloc(arraysize, sizeof(long));
    if(gradient)
    {
        for(i=0;i<arraysize;i++)
        {
            gradient[i] = get_int();
        }
        iGradient = get_gradient(gradient, arraysize);
        //free gradient when done getting result
        free(gradient);
    }

    return 0;
}

int get_gradient(int *a, int num)
{
    int grad = 0, i;
    //do something here to compute gradient
    return grad;    
}

long get_int(void)
{
    char input[80]={0};
    char **dummy={0};
    char* fmt = "%[^\n]%*c";
    printf("Enter integer number and hit return:\n");
    scanf(fmt, input);
    return strtol(input, dummy, 10);
}
```

Comment: Okay, this works for a set number of values, however I ask the user how many values they would like to input so the amount of values varies every time. Can this problem be overcame?

Comment: @JoshMulkeen - Just curious why you de-selected the check mark?  I know this is completely up to you, but is my answer missing something?

Comment: @JoshMulkeen - I see you re-selected.  Thank you.  I asked, not because I cared about the points, but because I assumed that the general response to your question has bothered you, at least a little.   For what it is worth, I have seen the same response to questions I have asked.  It is never pleasant.   The C/C++ boards in particular are excessively picky with questions (and answers), trending it would appear toward an ironic exclusivity that prefers accomplished programmers over beginners.  Overall though, it is a useful site.  I hope you will not let this bother you too much....

Comment: @JoshMulkeen - ...If you would like, please feel free to delete your question.  If so, I think you must first de-select the check-mark before it will allow you to delete.  Again, I do not care about the points.  Cheers.

Comment: I know what you mean with the 'pickyness', to be honest I just need to pass this class and I have since solved my problem. I'll give you the answer because it will probably help somebody else in the future haha

Comment: @JoshMulkeen - _just need to pass this class_.  Lol, I remember those days.  Ok, If you change your mind, delete it, its fine.  Good luck with your class.